How to resolve "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a];?
I am new to Java and Hibernate. I'm trying to write some tests, but I ran into a problem for which I can't find a solution.
How can I remove the error "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; ?
Error:
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException:
could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["FKRBAN5YEABNX30SEQM69JW44E: PUBLIC.VISIT FOREIGN KEY(PATIENT_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.PATIENT(ID) (3)"; SQL statement:
delete from patient where id=? [23503-197]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement


My code:
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class PatientDaoTest
{

    @Autowired
    private PatientDao patientDao;

    @Autowired
    private DoctorDao doctorDao;

    @Autowired
    private VisitDao visitDao;


    @Transactional
    @Test
    public void testLab2Patient() {
        long patientID = 3;

        //given
        long patientEntitiesNumBefore = patientDao.count();
        long doctorEntitiesNumBefore = doctorDao.count();
        long visitEntitiesNumBefore = visitDao.count();

        //when
        final PatientEntity saved = patientDao.getOne(patientID);
        patientDao.delete(saved.getId());

        //then
        final PatientEntity removed = patientDao.findOne(patientID);
        assertThat(removed).isNull();
        assertThat(doctorDao.count()).isEqualTo(doctorEntitiesNumBefore);
        assertThat(visitDao.count()).isEqualTo(visitEntitiesNumBefore-1);

    }
}

This is causing my error:
assertThat(visitDao.count()).isEqualTo(visitEntitiesNumBefore-1);

My solution to the problem:
OneToOne(orphanRemoval=true) or OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true)

Thank you very much M. Rizzo

It looks like you have a foreign key constraint of patient to visit.  You are not going to be able to delete the patient, because there are still visit records that reference the patient.  You would need to remove the reference of the patient on the visits or delete the visits, before deleting the patient.

I found a solution. Just add: OneToOne(orphanRemoval=true) or OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true)
